# How do I know which process is what program?

Tags: process, task-manager, application

Task manager shows a list of processes running. How do I find out, what process is what program? Sure the list shows the name of the exe-file, but I want to know the name of the program. Also I would like to be able to get info and manage those programs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: +1 @talonx. One of the must have tools for windows administration. Gives real details of the processes.

Answer (score 2):

Tasklist (technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) is a stock program (Windows XP and higher?) that is similar to Task Manager, but can also break down the services for you.  I know this isn't exactly what you want, but it could help.

```
tasklist /svc
```

Also, as Talonx mentioned, Process Explorer (technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is a great tool.  Along with all of the Sysintegrals (technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obligatory, already mentioned [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), there is a free tool: ProcessScanner. It generates a detailed list of the running processes and which porgrams they are associated with. The list is shown in the web browser.

[image]

Two similar programs, which are task manangers which show additional information to the processes are [**"What's Running"**](http://www.whatsrunning.net/whatsrunning/main.aspx) and [**"DTaskManager"**](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) (scroll down). Both are free.

**What's Running**

[image]
<sub>(source: [freewarewiki.com](http://freewarewiki.com/f/whatsrunning_th.png))</sub>

**DTaskManager**

[image]
<sub>(source: [altervista.org](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/dtaskmanager.gif))</sub>